# Android onRotate locale goes away

Tags: android, locale

I have two activities:

-> Main Activity

-> Configuration Activity

From 'MainActivity' I open the 'ConfigurationActivity'. This 'ConfigurationActivity' is shown in horizontal screen for small devices.

After click on 'Save Button', I re-open the 'MainActivity'. Because the 'ConfigurationActivity' is shown in horizontal screen, the 'MainActivity' is also shown in horizontal screen.

If I flip the phone to vertical screen I lose my locale configuration.

This is my code to set locale:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(lang); 
Resources res = getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = locale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
refresh.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(refresh);
finish();
```

I have tried to force, in Manifest, on 'MainActivity', the locale and orientation without success.

```
<activity
    android:name="main.myproject.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_mainactivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
    android:configChanges="locale|orientation" >
</activity>
```

Could be the solution to save the locale into a preference, then on method Create() in 'MainActivity' call that preference?

Thanks.

**Edit (1):**

The code below doesn't work. It continues to, whenever I flip the screen from horizontal to vertical, it changes the application language by itself. I only have two languages, the mother one: Portuguese and the second one: English.

In 'ConfigurationActivity', I've changed my code to:

```
public void setLocale(String lang) { 
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang); 
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = locale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

    SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("localePref", 0);
    sPrefs.edit().putString("lang", lang).commit();

    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    refresh.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(refresh);
    finish();
}
```

And in the 'MainActivity' I've created a method to call the language.

```
private void load_language(){
    SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("localePref", 0);
    String lang = sPrefs.getString("lang", "pt_PT");

    Locale locale = new Locale(lang); 
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = locale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

I 'override' the functions onCreate() and onConfigurationChanged():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_MainActivity);
    load_language();
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_MainActivity);
    load_language();
}
```

I've 'log.e' the value from the preference and the values is right. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what exactly doesnt work?  Also, xml just accepts lower_case_letters, it won't find any resource when there is capital letters like "MainActivity"

Answer (score 1):

An orientation-change re-builds the whole activity. This way all the Variables and their values get re-created aswell. So your idea to save it in local Preferences is probably the best solution here.

Saving:

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myAppsPreferences", 0);
sPrefs.edit().putBoolean("myKeyHere", value).commit();
```

Loading:

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myAppsPreferences", 0);
Boolean bCheck = sPrefs.getBoolean("MyKeyHere", defaultValue);
```

works for other primitive datatypes aswell!